# set source bitmapimage from Memorystream

Tags: windows-phone-7

I have application for wp7. I am necessary get BitmapImage from Byte array.   I do it so:

```
using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(rawImageBytes))

                {               
                    BitmapImage imageSource1 = new BitmapImage();
                    imageSource1.CreateOptions = BitmapCreateOptions.None;
                    imageSource1.SetSource(stream);
                }
```

After running, in string *imageSource1.SetSource(stream);*  I have error
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I am doing this several times without problem. Perhaps, it is only because your rawImageBytes have no Header information. For using rawImageBytes you need to use WritableBitmap. And I recommend WriteableBitmapExtension
http://writeablebitmapex.codeplex.com/releases/view/39577

```
wr = New WriteableBitmap(New Io.MemoryStream(rawImageBytes))
```

Also interesting post with basics:
http://www.windowsphonegeek.com/articles/encode-and-decode-images-in-wp7

Answer (score 0):

stream.Dispose() will be called at the end of using statement. imageSource1 will throw exception when it finds its source to be a dead stream.

Answer (score 0):

I believe Jay's answer is right.

The using statement will cause the Dispose() method to be called on the MemoryStream.
This signals to the garbage collector that some disposal needs to be done before cleaning up the MemoryStream reference. So it would require two Collect executions of the garbage collector before the object is fully removed.

The reason why the problem doesn't manifest all the time is exactly because the MemoryStream is still accessible as long as the garbage collector hasn't run yet. However, as soon as the GC has run, your MemoryStream reference is in an unusable state.